# jQuery adding CSS classes to links in order to display an icon next to the links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I'm wondering how I can use jQuery to add a CSS class to links that have a specific file extension on them. As long as jQuery can be used with the same principles as javascript I can probably figure out filtering correct links myself, but I'm not too certain as to how I can use the jQuery script to make these changes and how I should handle the icons.

The icons are already on the webpage, like so:

```
<img src="img/download.png" alt="download">
```

Does this mean that I can refer to the icons with their alts (for example "download") within the jQuery file that is being run in the HTML background?

Comment: may this help you:  $('img[src$=".png"]')  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach any part of the elements attributes. For example, if you wanted to use the `alt` attribute as the class, you can do this:

```
var $imgs = $("img");
$imgs.each(function(){
  var c = $(this).attr("alt");
  $(this).attr("class", c);
});
```

This will look for each `<img>`, and populate the `class` attribute with the value from the `alt` attribute.

As you mentioned, you can filter this down, I would advise using a more specific selector.

You can compress it some too:

```
$("img").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr("alt"));
});
```

**EDIT**

If you wish to place the an `<img>` before each `<a>` tag or within in, this would be different.

```
$("a").each(function(i, el){
  var $a = $(el);
  if($a.attr("href").indexOf(".pdf") > 0){
    var $icon = $("<img>", {
      src: "img/download.png",
      alt: "download"
    }).appendTo("body").position({
      my: "right+5 top",
      at: "left top",
      of: $a
    });
  }
});
```

Since you did not provide an example of the `<img>` tag as it relates to the `<a>` tag in your HTML, it is hard to know exactly where things are. You can use `.position()` or you can use CSS to style the icon before the link.

Comment: $("img").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("class", $( "a[href*='.pdf']" ));
});

I'm trying to apply the picture to any elements from a href with the .pdf string in it 

(The links are in elements like these:)

<a href="http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf">ECMAScript Language Specification (an external PDF)</a>

but I'm doing something wrong here. I feel like I'm still not grasping properly as to how the picture itself is commanded to go next to the HTML element

Comment: @Grak maybe I misunderstood your post. I thought you wanted to take the value of `alt` field and assign it as the `class` for the element. It sounds like you want ti iterate over links that are directed to PDF files and place an icon before the link. I will edit my answer.

Comment: After testing around with your new script I figured out a way to get the images into the right HTML elements, but I'm still facing difficulties: 
The images are added to all of the <li> elements instead of only the ones that have the appropriate file extension (or string in their name) and it appears 5 times

  `}).appendTo("li").position({`

I feel like I need to either get a selector to appendTo or then the selector searching for ".pdf" is looping too many times and adds the images to all the <li> elements when it finds a single <li> -element with the appropriate file extension

Comment: `li` is too ambiguous

Comment: `}).prependTo($a).position({`
adds only one and on the left side, but still to every single link instead of the correct ones only. Trying to figure out how to apply so that prepend only adds them to the correct elements

Comment: @Grak what is the element you are trying to select? You didn't include this in your post. Nor a very good example.

Comment: All the link elements are inside one <a href> </a href> and each individual link in <li> </li>, but I was able to make it work acceptably well with 

  `if($a.attr("href").indexOf(".pdf")>1){`

and 

  `}).appendTo($a).position({`

Comment: @Grak it looks like you got the answer in another post. Since JS does not eval -1 to false, you need to adjust comparing `.indexOf() > -1` instead. You can also use the `$("a[href*='pdf']")` or `$("a[href$='pdf']")` selector.

Comment: How does that selector "read out"? I think I might've screwed up adding that selector to the code I was running with so that might've caused me woes, as initially the HTML page flagged a lot of should-be valid code and I was troubleshooting it pretty randomly. 

Does it just point to "<a href>" and select the elements with "'pdf' somewhere in them due to the "*=" ?

Comment: jQuery selectors select the various HTML Elements and creates a jQuery Object. So, the selector `$("a[href*='pdf']")` will result in a jQuery Object that is the combined `<a>` elements that has an `href` attribute that contains `"pdf"` in it. `$("a[href$='pdf']")` will result in a jQuery Object that is the combined `<a>` elements that has an `href` attribute that end with `"pdf"`. The `.each()` can then iterate over each of these elements and perform a function upon them. See more: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

A much better approach would be to use pure CSS and psuedo elements. You would use :before or :after depending on where you want the icon to appear.

For example, if you want to target links that end with .pdf, you can use the following code. Place your image in the content: ""

```
a[href$=".pdf"]:after {
    background : url(img/download.png) no-repeat;
    content : "";
}
```

You can even get fancier and target links that are pdf AND open in a new window (target="_blank")

```
a[href$=".pdf"][target=_blank]:after {
    background : url(img/download.png) no-repeat;
    content : "";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting an uncaught syntax error from it:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

But the good news is that I'm understanding the architecture of the website a little bit better!

Comment: Syntax error is most likely being caused by some JavaScript you have. Keep in mind the code above is CSS, not JS. It should be placed into a stylesheet.css file or wrapped in <style> tags.